# I need to block device orientation in mobile and tab react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to block  landscape  mode in phone view,
and in (Tab)  ,I need to block
Portrait mode  is it possible
? Any one knows how to fix this both Android and iOS.Please share your idea